# AddText in pptxgenjs flexible width issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerpoint, keynote

I am trying to achieve a result like this

[image]

But the width of text automatically takes way more space than expected.

[image]

The text behavior is like div but I want it to behave like span
How to achieve something like this in [pptxgenjs](https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS#adding-text).

Comment: Are you able to change styles? Try to set `display: inline` property.

Comment: I got a reply from the owner. It's not possible apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer officially from the owner of repo which I want to share here.

> Hi @the-yadu ,
>
> Yeah, this gets asked periodically, but there's no fix per se. Objects
>   have to have a specified width - even ones with an auto-size property
>   set - and there's no way for the code to know how wide "RalphLauren"
>   is.
>
> Best I can tell, PowerPoint does this type of thing in the app itself,
>   not in the generated XML, so I'm unable to mimic it.